# Pass case class to Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, case-class

I have a scala-2.11 function which creates a case class from Map based on the provided class type.

```
def createCaseClass[T: TypeTag, A](someMap: Map[String, A]): T = {

    val rMirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val myClass = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
    val cMirror = rMirror.reflectClass(myClass)

    // The primary constructor is the first one
    val ctor = typeOf[T].decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asTerm.alternatives.head.asMethod
    val argList = ctor.paramLists.flatten.map(param => someMap(param.name.toString))

    cMirror.reflectConstructor(ctor)(argList: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

I'm trying to use this in the context of a spark data frame as a UDF. However, I'm not sure what's the best way to pass the case class. The approach below doesn't seem to work.

```
def myUDF[T: TypeTag] = udf { (inMap: Map[String, Long]) =>
    createCaseClass[T](inMap)
  }
```

I'm looking for something like this-

```
case class MyType(c1: String, c2: Long)

val myUDF = udf{(MyType, inMap) => createCaseClass[MyType](inMap)}
```

Thoughts and suggestions to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I'm not sure what's the best way to pass the case class

It is not possible to use case classes as arguments for user defined functions. SQL `StructTypes` are mapped to dynamically typed (for lack of a better word) `Row` objects.

If you want to operate on statically typed objects please use statically typed `Dataset`.

Answer (score 2):

From try and error I learn that whatever data structure that is stored in a Dataframe or Dataset is using org.apache.spark.sql.types

You can see with:

```
df.schema.toString
```

Basic types like Int,Double, are stored like:

```
StructField(fieldname,IntegerType,true),StructField(fieldname,DoubleType,true)
```

Complex types like case class are transformed to a combination of nested types:

```
StructType(StructField(..),StructField(..),StructType(..))
```

Sample code:

```
case class range(min:Double,max:Double)
org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[range].schema

//Output:
 org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(min,DoubleType,false), StructField(max,DoubleType,false))
```

The UDF parameter type in this cases is Row, or Seq[Row] when you store an array of case classes

A basic debug technic is print to string:

```
 val myUdf = udf( (r:Row) =>   r.schema.toString )
```

then, to see was happen:

```
df.take(1).foreach(println) //
```